# when to use assert.doesNotReject method in nodejs

Tags: node.js

When I go through the node.js documentation, I came across an assert package method call `assert.doesNotReject`, to my understanding, it is something to do with asynchronous code testing, but could not clearly understand the example mentioned in the documentation, can anyone explain me what is the purpose of this method and when to use this, so it will be useful to me and others as well (since I didnt find any other useful resource) for this?

Answer (score 0):

It is used for testing that a returned [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is not rejected asynchronously.

Although, it is even mentioned directly in the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_doesnotreject_asyncfn_error_message) that...

> Using `assert.doesNotReject()` is actually not useful because there is little benefit in catching a rejection and then rejecting it again.

This is analogous to catching an error/exception just to throw it again, without executing any error handling code. It is suggested to add comments next to the specific code path in which a Promise should not be rejected.

## Edit

You can try running the following code in Node and see the output for yourself.

In this case, however, it is obvious that the function is throwing an exception always, but it is only the target exception of `assertDoesNotReject` in the latter function.

The inherent nature of `assertDoesNotReject` is that if the function were to reject the promise (with or without the wrapping with `assertDoesNotReject`), an error would be thrown regardless. So you have a choice of either dealing with the error thrown by the rejection or wrapping it with `assertDoesNotReject` and supplying a meaningful message to accompany that exception.

Another situation is if you have some higher-order `AssertionError` catching logic and would prefer to handle that instead of an exception thrown after a Promise rejection.

```
const assert = require('assert');

(async () => {
    try {
        await assert.doesNotReject(
            async () => {
                throw new TypeError('Wrong value');
            },
            SyntaxError
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.stack);
    }
})();

(async () => {
    try {
        await assert.doesNotReject(
            async () => {
                throw new SyntaxError('Some syntax problem');
            },
            SyntaxError
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.stack);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Does it really do nothing? Does it perhaps alter the exception message or add the location of this assert to the traceback?

Comment: It does alter the exception message, however, in my testing, it replaced the stack trace altogether. It is, therefore, really only useful for the message that you pass as the third argument to `assert.doesNotReject()` because otherwise it will be difficult to determine where it came from. See my edit, for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in your unit / integration tests to check that an (async) function doesn't throw any errors (or any of the specified errors).